# ruby on rails parameter compare date with datetime?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, date, activerecord

I receive this parameter: `param[:date] = '2017-03-04'`

and the column in my database is created_at with this format: `'2017-01-01 09:21:23'`

When I execute this query

```
Mymodel.where(created_at: params[:date])
```

It returns an empty array, and it is logic due the time that is not passed

I need all the rows that corresponds to the param date.

How can I do this? The time is not important in this case, I only need the date.
I am using postgres as db.

I need to select e.g. All Sell of a specific day and the column to search is created_at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a type-coercion problem. Because the `created_at` field contains a date and time, your date is being converted into `2017-03-04 00:00:00` for the query. Anything that doesn't exactly match that timestamp will be excluded.

There are two approaches to solving this problem.

#### Database agnostic

Turn your date into a [Range object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html). ActiveSupport provides the [`Date#all_day`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-all_day) helper for this use-case.

```
date = Date.parse(params[:date])

MyModel.where(created_at: date.all_day)
```

Since `Date::parse` throws an exception if parsing fails, the real-world implementation would have to account for that

```
my_models = begin
  date = Date.parse(params[:date])

  MyModel.where(created_at: date.all_day)
rescue ArgumentError
  MyModel.all
end
```

#### Postgres

You can cast your `created_at` field to `date` so that only the date part will be matched.

```
MyModel.where("created_at::date = ?", params[:date])
```

Comment: and change the create_at format only in the sql query is posible? just to take 2017-01-01 and skip the time?

Comment: @matQ that can be done depending on what DB you are using. Please specify and I might be able to go into more detail.

Comment: @matQ I see now that you said you're using Postgres. I'll add an example for that

Comment: one more help... how can add other parameter? e.g
MyModel.where("created_at::date = ?", params[:date], seller_id: params[:seller_id])<= this is not woorking, please help. thanks in advance

Comment: @matQ you can add as many params as you need `where("created_at::date = ?, seller_id = ?", params[:date], params[:seller_id])`. Or you can chain `where`s, which I think is cleaner `where("created_at::date = ?", params[:date]).where(seller_id: params[:seller_id])`